# Batch program not starting on Windows 10

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10

I was just working on a small little batch program for fun, but when I went to test it, cmd flashed for half a second and then closed. I can't tell if my file is too big (it is not even fully finished) or if my code is wrong. Can someone take a look?
Code:

```
cls
title NyxManager - Login
cls
echo Loading files...
cls
echo Loading Buildtools...
cls
echo Loading Spigot...
cls
echo Reading Buildtools...
cls
echo Reading Spigot...
cls
echo Finished!
echo.
echo.
echo.
cls
echo Please Insert Username.
p /set username=
cls
echo Please Insert Password.
p /set password=
cls
echo Hello %username%! Password set to %password%!
echo.
echo.
echo.
cls
goto desktop
desktop:
cls
title NyxManager - Desktop
cls
echo [1] Start server
echo [2] Shutdown
p /set desktopoptions=
if %desktopoptions%==1 goto serverstart
if %desktopoptions%==2 quit
serverstart:
cls
title NyxManager - Server Console
cls
echo Welcome to the Server Console %username%!
echo.
echo.
echo.
cls
echo [1] Start Server
echo [2] Go Back
echo [3] Shutdown
p /set serverstartoptions=
if %desktopoptions%==1 goto serverconsole
if %desktopoptions%==2 goto desktop
if %desktopoptions%==3 quit
serverconsole:
cls
title NyxManager - Server Console
cls
echo Please select the Spigot version you are using.
echo [1] 1.11
echo [2] 1.11.2
p /set serverversion=
if %serverversion%==1 goto oneelevenconsole
if %serverversion%==2 goto oneeleventwoconsole
oneelevenconsole:
cls
title NyxManager - 1.11 Server Console
cls
echo Would you like to start the server?
echo [1] Yes
echo [2] No
p /set startservereleven=
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding `@echo off` at the start, also you should put the code directly here.

Comment: Did that, cmd still crashes...

Comment: Code you are having problems with should be posted here on StackOverflow otherwise your question will most likely be voted to be closed.

Comment: I can't post it in a reply. It's too long.

Comment: You post the portion of the code that you are having problems with. You don't post it in a comment, you EDIT your question!!!! http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You should consider reading the help file for the commands you are trying to use.  This would have helped you get past all the simple syntax errors you are having.

Comment: To debug a batch file you run the batch file from the cmd prompt and make sure `ECHO` is ON.  If you double click the batch file it just closes the window when it crashes.  If you run the batch file from the command prompt you will immediately see what line of code it crashed on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch Label should be defined as

```
:desktop
```

as opposed to

```
desktop:
```

and syntax for taking input from user is

```
set /p desktopoptions= "Enter choice"
```

^Note the space after equals sign.

while your code

```
p /set desktopoptions=
```

and there's no such command named 'quit'. I'd recommend

```
if %desktopoptions%==1 goto serverstart
if %desktopoptions%==2 goto exit

:exit
cls
echo exiting..
pause
exit
```

Comment: I forgot my morning coffee! Stupid mistakes... thank you anyways!

Comment: See more edits above

Comment: its still not working. I have corrected all of that. I guess the file is too big.

Comment: You should include the code in your question and don't guess such things :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Eqh47JDs

Comment: It's not "*p /set desktopoptions*" instead "*set /p desktopoptions*". *sigh*

Comment: That's it. I'm getting my coffee... Work's now! Thanks! Next time I'll code when I have my coffee!

Comment: `set /p "desktopoptions=Enter choice "` or switch to [`choice` command](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) for _one-character user's input_ (it allows single key-presses to be captured from the keyboard).